# Additional Serializer Fields in Django REST Framework 3

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Situation**

I am creating a simple endpoint that allows for the creation of a user. I need a field that is not in my user model (i.e., `confirm_password`). I will run validation that compares this field and another field that is in my model, and then never use the additional field again in the serializer.

**Problem**

DRF version 3 has changed the process for accomplishing this, and I do not quite understand what the documentation is suggesting I do. See [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) for the documentation.

**Attempt at Solution**

I have created a `UserSerializer` that looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Checks to be sure that the received password and confirm_password
        fields are exactly the same
        """
        if data['password'] != data.pop('confirm_password'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Creates the user if validation succeeds
        """
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        # returns the proper auth model
        model = get_user_model()
        # fields that will be deserialized
        fields = ['password', 'confirm_password',
                  'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
        # fields that will be serialized only
        read_only_fields = ['is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        # fields that will be deserialized only
        write_only_fields = ['password' 'confirm_password']
```

I was hoping that popping `confirm_password` in `validate` would take care of my problems, but I just get the following:

> Got `KeyError` when attempting to get a value for field `confirm_password` on serializer `UserSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `OrderedDict` instance

Comment: Just a heads up, it's common for most people to put the `Meta` class at the top of the serializer, as it contains the majority of the information you are typically looking for.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are looking for a write-only field, as I'm assuming you won't want to display the password confirmation in the API. Django REST Framework introduced the `write_only` parameter in the 2.3.x timeline to complement the `read_only` parameter, so the only time validation is run is when an update is being made. The `write_only_fields` meta property was added around the same time, but it's important to understand how both of these work together.

The `write_only_fields` meta property will automatically add the `write_only` property to a field when it is automatically created, like for a `password` field on a `User` model. It *will not* do this for any fields which are not on the model, or fields that have been explicitly specified on the serializer. In your case, you are explicitly specifying the `confirm_password` field on your serializer, which is why it is not working.

> Got `KeyError` when attempting to get a value for field `confirm_password` on serializer `UserSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `OrderedDict` instance

This is raised during the re-serialization of the created user, when it is trying to serialize your `confirm_password` field. Because it cannot find the field on the `User` model, it triggers this error which tries to explain the problem. Unfortunately because this is on a *new* user, it tells you to confusingly look at the `OrderedDict` instance instead of the `User` instance.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False, write_only=True)
```

If you explicitly specify `write_only` on the serializer field, and remove the field from your `write_only_fields`, then you should see the behaviour your are expecting.

You can find documentation about this on this [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Also useful for nested serializer implementation representing models, when the root model doesn't have directly access to fields you want to use.
Thank you @vyscond ;)
Fyi here is my case:

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    permission_classes = (
        IsCompanyMember,
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='company name',
        null=False
    )
class Profile(models.Model):

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_company_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    is_email_validated = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    is_approved_by_company_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
```

serializer.py

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name',)

class CustomUserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'},
                                 write_only=True,
                                 validators=settings.get('PASSWORD_VALIDATORS'))

    company = CompanySerializer(allow_null=False, required=True,write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',
                  'email',
                  'password',
                  'company',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name')
```