# django rest framework validation & refreshing data

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

I am trying to validate whether password1, password2 are matching not using object level validation because it is executed after all field level validations, but validate_field only accepts one value. How can I implement the following in rest framework?

```
def validate_password2(self, data):
        print 'validating...'
        password1, password2 = data['password1'], data['password2']           
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2: 
              raise serializers.ValidationError('The two passwords do not match.')         
        return password2
```

And when errors occur, the data in the form are cleared. How can I retain the input data even when the errors occur like django form.fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding field-level validation, add this check to your object-level validation because you require access to multiple fields.

Even the DRF docs define this:

> Object-level validation
>
> To do any other validation that requires access to multiple fields,
>   add a method called .validate() to your Serializer subclass. This
>   method takes a single argument, which is a dictionary of field values.
>   It should raise a ValidationError if necessary, or just return the
>   validated values.

You can just do the following:

```
def validate(self, data):
    ...
    password1 = data['password1']
    password2 = data['password2']
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('The two passwords do not match.')
    ....
    return data
```

Also to access the initial data when errors have occured, you can use `your_serializer.initial_data`.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer.
If I have multiple fields that needs different validations then I have to add all that stuff in `validate` function. right ? and what will happen to built in validations like email validation.
What if I access `initial_data` in field level validator ? is it bad practice ?

Comment: If your multiple fields validations depend on each other, then you have to do that in `validate()` function, otherwise, do that in `validate_<fieldname>()` function. The built-in validations will hapen regardless of your custom validation, so you don't need to worry about it.  If you really need the `initial_data` for doing some validations, then you should use it.

Comment: Thanks, much helpful. Main concern was overriding `validate` will or will not override built-in validations. But now, clear.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for validating password in DRF

```
def validate_password2(self, attrs, source):
    """
    password_confirmation check
    """
    password_confirmation = attrs[source]
    password = attrs['password1']

    if password_confirmation != password:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('password didnot match')

    return attrs
```

Comment: I am using DRF v 3.1+, so does that accept attrs? As I know of, it only accept one value, the value of the field.

Comment: No idea regarding DRF 3.1+,please check this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591574/order-of-serializer-validation-in-django-rest-framework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591184/additional-serializer-fields-in-django-rest-framework-3