# using nested writable serializers in views gives AttributeError:

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to use nested serializer for order with order contents but getting attribute error

as per [Additional Serializer Fields in Django REST Framework 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591184/additional-serializer-fields-in-django-rest-framework-3) it is because the ordercontent field is not in order model

I searched for adding a non-model field to the serializer 
[Add a non-model field on a ModelSerializer in DRF 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597964/add-a-non-model-field-on-a-modelserializer-in-drf-3/37718821)
but still getting the error

one interesting thing is that it's giving no errors in `python manage.py shell`

serializers.py

```
class OrderContentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderContent
        fields = ('price',)




class OrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    order_contents = OrderContentSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('total_price', 'order_status', 'order_contents')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        contents_data = validated_data.pop('order_contents')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)        
        for data in contents_data:
            OrderContent.objects.create(order=order, **data)
        return order
```

views.py

```
class CreateOrderCustomer(APIView):
    # permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = serializers.OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(request.data)
            print(request.user)
            serializer.save(created_by=request.user)
            return Response(data=serializer.data,status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(data=serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i used python manage.py shell which successfully created the order

```
>>> from orders.serializers import OrderSerializer
>>> data={'totalprice': 3.0, 'order_status': 0, 'order_contents': [{'price': 18}, {'price': 12}]}
>>> serializer=OrderSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
>>> from users.models import User
>>> user=User.objects.get(username='1')
>>> serializer.save(created_by=user)
<Order: order7>
```

but doing same through views endpoint with the same data gives me

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `order_contents` on serializer `OrderSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Order` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Order' object has no attribute 'order_contents'.

Comment: i was able to make it work by adding ```required=False```  in orderserializer as   ```order_contents = OrderContentSerializer(many=True,required=False)```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532420/django-rest-framework-keeps-returning-error-on-nested-relationship